# Emacs tea-time is supposed to be integrated in org-mode, but apparently, it's not

Tags: package

I'm talking about [tea-time](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tea-time). In short:

> It allows you to set up time intervals and after this interval is elapsed, Emacs will notify you with sound and notification.

What I'm really interested in is the sound notification (otherwise, I'd miss it).

It also seys in the link that it's been integrated into org-mode:

> Functionality of this package was integrated into org-mode (edge on May 2009). Check http://orgmode.org/Changes.html#sec-1.4.2 for details.

I checked the link, but the only functionality that is mentioned is the use of `org-timer` (`org-timer-set-timer`, which I've been using for some time now). But `org-timer` doesn't have any (sound) notifications. Did I miss something?

Edit: It could be that I just don't know how to configure `org-timer` to play sounds. I'm not very good with lisp code (yet), can somebody please help me out on this?

Edit2: I found this piece of code [org-timer.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-timer.el;hb=HEAD):

```
(defun org-timer--run-countdown-timer (secs title)
  "Start countdown timer that will last SECS.
TITLE will be appended to the notification message displayed when
time is up."
  (let ((msg (format "%s: time out" title)))
    (run-with-timer
     secs nil `(lambda ()
         (setq org-timer-countdown-timer nil
               org-timer-start-time nil)
         (org-notify ,msg ,org-clock-sound)
         (org-timer-set-mode-line 'off)
         (run-hooks 'org-timer-done-hook)))))
```

I think org-clock-sound is a variable that I need to set to a specific *.wav file or something, but I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the org-clock-sound variable:

```el
(setq org-clock-sound nil) ;; no sound
(setq org-clock-sound t) ;; Standard Emacs beep
(setq org-clock-sound "/path/to/my/sound") ;; Play this sound file, fall back to beep
```