# How to get an audible feedback when the current task is overrun?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

In org-mode when a task is overrun - when the clocked time is bigger than the effort, there is a visual feedback in the mode-line. I am looking for a way to get an audible one as well.

I couldn't find [any hook for this event](http://orgmode.org/tmp/worg/org-configs/org-hooks.html). As for the implementation of [org-clock](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-clock.el;hb=HEAD) it appears to be only providing an extra string to display on the mode-line.

> "Extra mode line text to indicate that the clock is overrun.
>   The can be nil to indicate that instead of adding text, the clock time
>   should get a different face (org-mode-line-clock-overrun').
>   When this is a string, it is prepended to the clock string as an indication,
>   also using the face org-mode-line-clock-overrun'." (from org-clock-task-overrun-text)

Has anyone managed to find a way to get an audio feedback when the clock has just overrun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tyler's answer suggests, `org-clock-sound` will help org to make an audible feedback for this scenario.

However, it is highly probable that lost in the init file there is this line of code **preventing this feedback to happen**:

```
(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)
```

## Solution

- Make sure to **not have set to ignore** `ring-bell-function` or that you have **provided** a function like this:

  ```
  (setq ring-bell-function (lambda ()
                            (play-sound-file "/this/is/my/errorsound.au")))
  ```

  *(from [emacsWiki alarm bell](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlarmBell))*
- Set the `org-clock-sound` to `t` or your favorite sound [see this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17849/15515) for examples.

---

If you happen to be on a emacs version without the sound binaries on OSX, you may want to look at https://github.com/leoliu/play-sound-osx for a quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

The function `org-clock-notify-once-if-expired` appears to play a sound, if you have a sound configured in the variable `org-clock-sound`. That would give you a single audible notification after you first go over-time on a task:

```
...
  (if (setq org-clock-task-overrun
    (if (or (null effort-in-minutes) (zerop effort-in-minutes))
        nil
      (>= clocked-time effort-in-minutes)))
    (unless org-clock-notification-was-shown
      (setq org-clock-notification-was-shown t)
    (org-notify
     (format-message "Task `%s' should be finished by now. (%s)"
                         org-clock-heading org-clock-effort)
         org-clock-sound))
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights, it really helped me figuring out this out!